# How do I get Full Price including Custom Option on Add To Cart?

Tags: magento2

I want to get the Full Price, including the Custom Option price on Add To Cart.

I've tested using the **checkout_cart_add_product_complete** event with below observer:

```
class CheckoutCartAddProductObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
        $price = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getValue();
    }
}
```

Which gives me the final price of the product, but it doesn't include the price of the option. The option is of type dropdown, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this isn't working?

**app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
         <observer name="caraddcomplete" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\CartAddComplete"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Observer/CartAddComplete.php**

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CartAddComplete implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
        $isHasOptions = $product->getTypeInstance()->hasOptions($product);
        if ($isHasOptions) {
            $price = $product->getFinalPrice();
        }
    }
}
```